# how to index all metatags in nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

I have installed Nutch 1.9 and configured it to successfully crawl with Solr 4.10.1. I am trying to set Nutch to index metadata as outlined here https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags

How do I set it to index ALL of the metadata on a site? I set the value for metatags.names to *  like this

```html
<property>
    <name>metatags.names</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>Names of the metatags to extract, separated by ','. Use '*' to extract all metatags. Prefixes the names with 'metatag.' in the parse-metadata. For instance to index description and keywords, you need to activate the plugin index-metadata and set the
    value of the parameter 'index.parse.md' to 'metatag.description,metatag.keywords'.
    </description>
</property>
```

but I am unsure of how to set the value for index.parse.md without listing individual metatag names. I tried this

```html
<property>
    <name>index.parse.md</name>
    <value>meta*</value>
    <description>Comma-separated list of keys to be taken from the parse metadata to generate fields. Can be used e.g. for 'description' or 'keywords' provided that these values are generated by a parser (see parse-metatags plugin)
    </description>
</property>
```

but that doesn't display any metadata when running

```html
bin/nutch indexchecker http://nutch.apache.org/
```

and I am sure there is metadata on that site because it returns Parse Metadata when running

```html
bin/nutch parsechecker http://nutch.apache.org/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plugin index-metadata doesn't work that way. You have to specify complete name there, e.g. "metatag.keywords".

Also "metatags.names" value "*" is not really wildcard. You can't put something like "meta*" there as well.

Comment: This can't really be the final answer, is it?  Must we really know the full name of every metatag nutch could possibly encounter?  If so, are there any restrictions on field length?

Comment: @SeanO'Brien You can see it for yourself:
https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/parse-metatags
https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/index-metadata

I haven't been involved in any nutch related work since 2016, but it looks like these plugins haven't changed much since then.

Comment: while I have a hard time understanding what made that design decision seem like a good idea, it's hard to argue with the code.  You say you haven't been involved with nutch-related work...is there something else y'all use to crawl web content..perhaps without this type of limitation?  I'm trying to put together a faceted search that lets my content creators bucket content together on the fly, and I don't want to have to make them reconfigure nutch every time they add a new category.

Comment: @SeanO'Brien Check out https://scrapy.org/. I'm not sure about it's capabilities as I haven't used it yet, but I've heard that a lot of people use it.